# What happens when an exception is thrown while unwinding the stack from another exception?

Tags: exception

For example in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
     public:
           A() { cout << "A::A()" << endl; }
           ~A() { cout << "A::~A()" << endl; throw "A::exception"; }
     };
class B {
     public:
           B() { cout << "B::B()" << endl; throw "B::exception"; }
           ~B() { cout << "B::~B()"; }
     };
int main(int, char**)
{
     try {
           cout << "Entering try...catch block" << endl;
           A objectA;
           B objectB;
           cout << "Exiting try...catch block" << endl;
     }
     catch (char* ex) {
           cout << ex << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

`B`'s destructor throws an exception, which invokes `A`'s destructor while unwinding the stack, resulting in the throw of another exception.
What will be the program's reaction?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer? Bang, application termination.

From [parashift](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html):

During stack unwinding, all the local objects in all those stack frames are destructed. If one of those destructors throws an exception (say it throws a Bar object), the C++ runtime system is in a no-win situation: should it ignore the Bar and end up in the

```
} catch (Foo e) {
```

where it was originally headed? Should it ignore the Foo and look for a

```
} catch (Bar e) {
```

handler? There is no good answer — either choice loses information.

So the C++ language guarantees that it will call `terminate()` at this point, and `terminate()` kills the process. Bang you're dead.

**Related questions on Stack Overflow:**

- [Why exactly is calling the destructor for the second time undefined behavior in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771567/why-exactly-is-calling-the-destructor-for-the-second-time-undefined-behavior-in-c)
- [throwing exceptions out of a
  destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130117/throwing-exceptions-out-of-a-destructor)