# need to call the base destructor method from a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++, destructor, derived-class, base-class

Please consider the following:

```
class base{
    base();
    ~base();
}:

class derived : public base{

};
```

Does a base class destructor get automatically invoked when a derived object is destructed when the derived class has no destructor defined?

Otherwise, if I DO have a destructor in the derived class too, do I have to call the base class destructor explicitly?

```
class base{
    base();
    ~base();
}:

class derived : public base{
     derived();
     ~derived{
           base::~base(); //do I need this?
     }
};
```

Comment: No you don't need to do that - it's automatic

Comment: Note that you could answer this by simple experiment, by printing something out in the base destructor.

Comment: @Beta: you are right. But i preferred having a complete explanation of the subject. In fact now i realized that i should declare virtual my destructors in the base class. If I simply tried with a print statement i wouldn't realize that because actually i'm not calling any destructor on a base class reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The base class destructor is automatically invoked in this case; [you do not need to call it](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.12).

However, note that *when destroying an object through `delete` on a base class pointer and the destructor is not `virtual`, the result is going to be undefined behavior* (although you might not get a crash).

Always declare the destructor as `virtual` in any class which is meant to be derived from. If the base class does not need to have a destructor, include a `virtual` one anyway with an empty body.

There is an exception to the above rule for an edge case: *if your derived classes do not need to support polymorphic destruction*, then the destructor does not need to be `virtual`. In this case it would be correct to make it `protected` instead; [more details here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm), but be advised that this rarely occurs in practice.

Comment: The **base class** destructor is still executed. The **derived** isn't

Comment: That's kind of a weird statement, if you call delete on base class, only the base class destructor is invoked (if not virtual), so the base class destructor is invoked always :-D

Comment: "The wrong destructor will be called" is inaccurate. In fact, only the base destructor will be called, and UB will have been invoked.

Comment: @Erik, @Let_Me_Be: Writing for speed is on the expense of correctness. I corrected that as soon as I read it again.

Comment: @Jon: I can still read it as "the wrong destructor will be called"

Comment: @Jon : "Always declare the destructor as virtual in any class which is meant to be derived from". Do I need to do the same for constructors?

Comment: @Overbose: Constructors cannot be virtual.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal, @Als: Further edits and corrections made. Thank you for the comments and your patience, I can't multitask all that fast :)

Comment: @Jon: Ugh, no, do not make destructors `virtual` just for the sake of inheritance. Only if you intend to use polymorphism! Otherwise you're just forcing virtual dispatch for potentially no reason. You do talk about this, but as a rare "edge case".. and a protected destructor is only useful for an pure virtual base. KISS!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Unless you take explicit steps to *prevent* the class from being used polymorphically, I believe the destructor *must* be virtual (I would consider a design that bases correct behavior on a "DO NOT USE THIS POLYMORPHICALLY" comment to be flawed).

Comment: @Jon: :) We're verging into heavily subjective territory now, I guess. I prefer not to have heavy polymorphic classes running about all over my damned code, when I never use polymorphism on them.

Comment: @Erik: "The base class destructor is still executed" - behavior is undefined (5.3.5/3). Perhaps on your implementation the base class destructor is executed. Perhaps on mine it isn't.

Comment: @Jon: perhaps flawed, but certainly it is idiomatic C++ (almost all standard classes have public non-virtual destructors). I think a design that inherits from a C++ class that isn't explicitly documented to be suitable for inheritance is more severely flawed. Documenting "do not delete polymorphically" is a bit limiting, but if for example you want a POD class, then you *can't* give it a virtual or a protected destructor. Documentation is all that's left, so if users are determined to inherit from it and delete through pointer-to-base then it's their own stupidity they'll suffer for.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Agreed. But keep in mind that it does read "any class which is meant to be derived from". That would rule out POD and really a *lot* of other cases which would better be modeled by composition instead of inheritance, like the inheriting from class not supposed to be inherited from case that you mention.

Comment: @Jon: the "explicit step" to prevent polymorphic destruction is simply to define a protected destructor. (This assumes that the base class is abstract, but inheriting from a non-abstract class would be rather odd in my opinion).

Comment: @Jon: it all falls out nicely if you follow the advice that non-abstract classes must be leaf classes. Then you wouldn't inherit from a POD class, since of course it's not abstract. Your "edge cases" include things like CRTP and composition through private inheritance, where a class *is* intended (or at least suitable) for use as a base but clearly is *not* suitable for polymorphic deletion. How rare that is depends on coding style - you don't *have* to use dynamic polymorphism at all, and even when you do, if the dtor is non-virtual `shared_ptr<base>` can still safely delete derived objects.

Comment: ... which is not to say that I advise leaving the dtor non-virtual just because `shared_ptr` can cope, just that it's available as a workaround.

Comment: @Jon why "undefined behavior"?

Answer (score 2):

*Does a base class destructor is automatically invoked when a derived object is destructed and the derived class has no destructor defined?*
Yes, the Base class destructor is automatically invoked after the Derived class Destructor, irrespective of Derived class destructor being explicitly defined or not.

*Otherwise, if I have a destructor in the derived class too, do I need to call explicitly base class destructor too?*
No, You don't need to.
There will not be any scenario in C++, where one has to explicitly invoke a destructor except while using placement new.

Answer (score 1):

No, base destructors are invoked automatically in this case, in much the same way that base constructors <strike>are</strike> can be invoked automatically.

<sub>Note, though, that if you are using polymorphism and destroying through a base pointer, you should make *sure* that the destructor is virtual otherwise this will break.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You should ***never invoke a base class destructor from a derived class destructor***.

The reason is base class destructor will be then called automatically for the second time and writing destructors in such way that this doesn't cause problem is problematic - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2763275/57428).